# Compilation error with a class constraint on a phantom type in a default method

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, typeclass, phantom-types

This (somewhat nonsensical) module compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

module Foo where

class A t where
  f :: forall x m. Monoid x => t m -> m
  f = undefined

instance A [] where
  f = undefined
```

If I remove the instance's definition of `f`, I would expect it to inherit the method default and amount to the same thing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

module Foo where

class A t where
  f :: forall x m. Monoid x => t m -> m
  f = undefined

instance A [] where
```

This does not work, however. GHC 8.0.2 gives this error:

```
• Could not deduce (Monoid x0)
    arising from a use of ‘Foo.$dmf’
  from the context: Monoid x
    bound by the type signature for:
               f :: Monoid x => [m] -> m
    at src/Foo.hs:10:10-13
  The type variable ‘x0’ is ambiguous
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Monoid a => Monoid (IO a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
    instance Monoid Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
    instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
    ...plus 7 others
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the expression: Foo.$dmf @[]
  In an equation for ‘f’: f = Foo.$dmf @[]
  In the instance declaration for ‘A []’
```

I'm not sure how to read this error, because I don't know where the imaginary `x0` is being inserted. Why doesn't the second example compile?

Comment: I've opened a GHC issue: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14266

Answer (score 2):

GHC is basically converting your code to this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

module Foo where

defaultF :: forall t x m. (A t, Monoid x) => t m -> m
defaultF = undefined

class A t where
  f :: forall x m. Monoid x => t m -> m
  f = defaultF @t @x @m

instance A [] where
  f = defaultF @[]
```

Now, in the last line the type variable `x` is not in scope since we do not have an explicit `forall x`. Even if it were, it is not passed to `defaultF` as an explicit type argument. So, the last `defaultF` call could be made on any monoid at all, possibly another one!

For that call, the inference engine generates a fresh `x0` type variable, hence the type error message :-(

Maybe GHC's instance deriving mechanism should be updated, now that ambiguous types are allowed (which is a good thing, IMO).

For a simpler case, consider

```
a :: forall x. Monoid x => Int
a = undefined

b :: forall x. Monoid x => Int
b = a
```

The last call *needs* a disambiguating explicit type argument, in Haskell. It would work fine in dependently typed languages like Agda/Idris/Coq/... since these (by default, at least) pass their type arguments explicitly.